# Communication with sockets using threads

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I'm currently programming a python class which acts as a client.
Because I don't want to block the main thread, receiving of packets is done in another thread and a callback function is called if a packet arrives.

The received packets are either broadcast messages or a reply for a command sent by the client. The function for sending commands is synchronous, it blocks until the reply arrives so it can directly return the result.

Simplified example:

```
import socket
import threading

class SocketThread(threading.Thread):
    packet_received_callback = None

    _reply = None
    _reply_event = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        self._initialize_socket()

        while True:
            # This function blocks until a packet arrives
            p = self._receive_packet()

            if self._is_reply(p):
                self._reply = p
                self._reply_event.set()
            else:
                self.packet_received_callback(p)

    def send_command(self, command):
        # Send command via socket
        self.sock.send(command)

        # Wait for reply
        self._reply_event.wait()
        self._reply_event.clear()

        return self._process_reply(self._reply)
```

The problem which I'm facing now is that I can't send commands in the callback function because that would end in a deadlock (send_command waits for a reply but no packets can be received because the thread which receives packets is actually executing the callback function).

My current solution is to start a new thread each time to call the callback function. But that way a lot of threads are spawned and it will be difficult to ensure that packets are processed synchronously in heavy traffic situations.

Does anybody know a more elegant solution or am I going the right way?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Normally this is the kind of thing best done with e.g. the twisted library.  Trying to do it on your own via thread objects is likely to result in a lot of confusion.  For instance, are you familiar with threading issues surrounding the global interpreter lock (the GIL)?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. No I've never heared of it. I will do some research and have a look on that library.

Comment: I think threading is a valid approach in this case since Event.wait() and socket.recv() should both release the GIL while they wait. Of course this depends on the details of the work being done..

Comment: Certainly it can be done with threading, and as long as you're careful to use those functions that release the GIL that will be okay, but in general I think rolling your own multithreaded network app is quite difficult and full of pitfalls and twisted or another full-fledged networking library helps a lot.

Comment: In consideration of the problems you mentioned (found an interesting article [here](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/03/31/pythons-hardest-problem/)) I think I'll try to design the application single-threaded. The protocol is that simple (as I mentioned in the comment below I'm communicating with [LIRC](http://www.lirc.org)) that I think it isn't worth loading such a big library.

Answer (score 0):

A proper answer to this question depends a lot on the details of the problem you are trying to solve, but here is one solution:

Rather than invoking the callback function immediately upon receiving the packet, I think it would make more sense for the socket thread to simply store the packet that it received and continue polling for packets. Then when the main thread has time, it can check for new packets that have arrived and act on them.

Comment: I think that way the additional thread isn't useful anymore. Wouldn't it be easier to use the socket.setblocking(False) function and make the whole application single-threaded? The application is used to process received IR commands and send IR commands using [LIRC](http://www.lirc.org/) (uses a unix socket interface). Because I started learning python just a few months ago I thought it could be a nice project to learn something about multithreading in python.

Answer (score 0):

Recently had another idea, let me know how you think about it. It's just a general approach to solve such problems in case someone else has a similar problem and needs to use multi-threading.

```
import threading
import queue

class EventBase(threading.Thread):
    ''' Class which provides a base for event-based programming. '''

    def __init__(self):
        self._event_queue = queue.Queue()

    def run(self):
        ''' Starts the event loop. '''

        while True:
            # Get next event
            e = self._event_queue.get()

            # If there is a "None" in the queue, someone wants to stop
            if not e:
                break

            # Call event handler
            e[0](*e[1], **e[2])
            # Mark as done
            self._event_queue.task_done()

    def stop(self, join=True):
        ''' Stops processing events. '''

        if self.is_alive():
            # Put poison-pill to queue
            self._event_queue.put(None)
            # Wait until finished
            if join:
                self.join()

    def create_event_launcher(self, func):
        ''' Creates a function which can be used to call the passed func in the event-loop. '''

        def event_launcher(*args, **kwargs):
            self._event_queue.put((func, args, kwargs))

        return event_launcher
```

Use it like so:

```
event_loop = eventbase.EventBase()
event_loop.start()

# Or any other callback
sock_thread.packet_received_callback = event_loop.create_event_launcher(my_event_handler)

# ...

# Finally
event_loop.stop()
```